# Google map compass button is disappear when I enabled

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift

I have turned on the compass button in the setting, but the google map does not show any compass button. Is the navigation bar cover the compass button or actually it is not enabled?

[image]

swift code:

```
        camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(lat,longitude:long, zoom:17.5, bearing:0, viewingAngle:0)
        mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera:camera)
        mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
        mapView.settings.indoorPicker = true
        mapView.settings.compassButton = true
        mapView.indoorEnabled = true
        mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compass has been hidden by the navigation bar.

I have add the code at the below to move the compass:

swift:

```
        if let nav_height = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height
        {
           let status_height = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height

            mapView.padding = UIEdgeInsetsMake (nav_height+status_height,0,0,0);
        }
```

Comment: this means with reducing mapView size, can be see the compass button? **but I cant**

Comment: Please describe more on your situation like do you enable compass, compass location where you put in screen etc

Comment: i resize (with `CGRect`) the `mapView` and consider `bearing`, and the can see the compass.